# Why magnet is always a dipole?

Tags: magnetic-fields, dipole, ferromagnetism

Why magnet is alway dipole
Even the atom of the magnetic substance is also dipole , how can small atom be dipole . Pls explain me

Comment: This is one of the big questions since the math seems to say that a monopole should be possible, we just can't seem to find or make any.

Comment: @DKNguyen Not the math but the physics says that a monopole is impossible.

Comment: I mean, the math doesn't say it should be possible, since the condition is the Div B is zero, any one could therefore say anything about any vector field "should be possible" as divergence is a property of any vector field

Comment: @jensenpaull I think there's math beyond Maxwell. The weird stuff.

Comment: @my2cts I'm pretty confident you could get a Nobel prize if you could convince people that magnetic monopoles are impossible. You may want to publish ASAP if you have evidence of this.

Comment: @d_b The Maxwell equations exclude a monopole and experiment is fully in agreement with these.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the "why" is a tough question, we can only describe reality how we currently see it. Mathematically it is because $\nabla \cdot B = 0$ the magnetic field always creates closed loops as you can only create a curl in the magnetic field. This is an experimental fact

Answer (score 1):

That there are no magnetic monopoles is mostly an arbitrary choice of coordinates (or gauge).

Maxwell's equations have a 'rotational' symmetry between the electric and magnetic fields, as described [in this Stack Exchange question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/499866/symmetry-of-maxwell-equations-for-electric-magnetic-duality).

Through a 'rotation' of $\alpha$, the divergence (e.g. charge density / monopole density) of the electric and magnetic fields may be made to satisfy:
$$ \epsilon_0 \nabla \cdot \vec{E}' = \rho_e' =  \rho_e \cos \alpha + \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \rho_m \sin \alpha$$
$$ \frac 1 {\mu_0 } \nabla \cdot \vec{B}' = \rho_m' =  \rho_m \cos \alpha - \frac{\rho_e}{\mu_0 \epsilon_0} \sin \alpha $$
Clearly, adding $\pi$ to $\alpha$ makes each of the two densities above negative. By the intermediate value theorem, there is some value of $\alpha$ which will make the *electric* monopole density zero, and the magnetic non-zero:
$$ \alpha = \arctan \left(-\frac{\rho_e}{\rho_m} \frac{1}{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}\right) $$
$$ \nabla \cdot \vec{E}' = 0$$
$$ \frac 1 {\mu_0 } \nabla \cdot \vec{B}' = \rho_m' = -2 \frac{\rho_e}{\mu_0 \epsilon_0} \sin\left( \alpha \right) = \left[1 + \left(\frac{\rho_m}{\rho_e} \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \right)^{2} \right]^{-1/2}$$
Since in the traditional formulation of Maxwell's equations the magnetic charge density is set to zero, $\rho_m = 0$, we may rotate all of the electric monopole to the magnetic by setting $\alpha = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$. Then:
$$ \nabla \cdot \vec{E}' = 0$$
$$ \nabla \cdot \vec{B}' = \pm \frac{2 \rho_e}{\mu_0 \epsilon_0} $$
(You may want to check my math with the exact coefficients)

My point is that **asking why there are no magnetic monopoles is asking the wrong question**. An arbitrary coordinate transformation can always make it appear that one of the two coupled fields has zero divergence (no monopoles) at any chosen point $\vec{x}$ in space. The right question to be asking is **why do all monopoles come with the same (or negative) ratio of electric:magnetic charge?**. This is what makes it possible to eliminate one of $\rho_m$ or $\rho_e$ through a change of coordinates.

I feel this is important to address because people can sometimes think that there is something special about the *magnetic* field having no monopoles. In fact that is a red herring. The fundamental symmetry is a common ratio of monopole charge in all observed particles.

The answer to the good question? I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

The dipole of permanent magnets is not a mystery if you know that electrons are electric charges and magnetic dipoles in one.

There are two ways to macroscopically enhance these properties:

- If you separate the electrons, you get a macroscopic electric field around the body of the charge.
- If you align the magnetic dipoles of the electrons (and the other subatomic particles ), you get a magnet.

The amazing thing about permanent magnets is their ability to maintain the magnetic alignment of the subatomic particles against the action of the thermal motion of the atoms.