# How do you express the electric and magnetic field of a TEM uniform plane wave due to a magnetic current density?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Given an infinite plane sheet of time-harmonic ($\text{e}^{j\omega t}$) electric and magnetic surface current densitites, $\textbf{J}_{es}$ & $\textbf{J}_{ms}$, respectively, is located in free space (with wavenumber $k$ and intrinsic impedance $\eta$) in the $xy$-plane of a rectangular $xyz$-coordinate system. For $z>0$ ($z<0$), each of these currents radiate a TEM (transverse electromagnetic) plane wave propagating in the positive (negative) direction of the $z$-axis. The fields of the electric and magnetic currents are denotes by ($\textbf{E}_e$,$\textbf{H}_e$) & ($\textbf{E}_m$,$\textbf{H}_m$), respectively.

We want to determine the total fields $\textbf{E}=\textbf{E}_e+\textbf{E}_m$ and $\textbf{H}=\textbf{H}_e+\textbf{H}_m$.

Now, my question is; how do we express the field of the TEM plane wave due to the magnetic current density?

I define the electric current density as $\textbf{J}_e=E_0\textbf{e}_x$ so the electromagnetic fields due to the electric current density are given as the solution to the wave equation; $\textbf{E}_e(z,t)=E_{0e}\text{cos}(kz-\omega t+a_x)\textbf{e}_x$ and $\textbf{H}_e(z,t)=H_{0e}\text{cos}(kz-\omega t+a_x)\textbf{e}_y$, but how does the field due to the fictitous magnetic current look like?

Comment: hint: (1) do you know how to calculate the fields given $\mathbf J_e$? (2)if introduced, where does the magnetic current show up in Maxwell's equation?

Comment: By magnetic current, do you mean a current of magnetic charges or a current of electric charges due to a magnetisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the fields generated by a current of magnetic charges, the [electric-magnetic duality relation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/499866/symmetry-of-maxwell-equations-for-electric-magnetic-duality) is of use.  It says that any solution of Maxwell's equations in vacuum may be transformed in the following way to get another solution to Maxwell's equations:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E} &\to \mathbf{B} & \mathbf{B} &\to - \mathbf{E} \\
\rho_e &\to \rho_m & \mathbf{J}_e &\to -\mathbf{J}_m
\end{align*}
(This is not the most general such transformation, but it's the most useful one in your case.  It does use units where $c = 1$, but it's easy enough to put them back in as needed.)

So to solve your magnetic problem for a source term $\mathbf{J}_m$, simply find the analogous solution for an *electric* current source term $\mathbf{J}'_e = - \mathbf{J}_m$, solve the electric problem for $\mathbf{J}'_e$ to find the $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ fields, and then apply the duality transformation on those resulting fields.