# Do the solutions to Maxwell's equations form a group?

Tags: electromagnetism, group-theory, maxwell-equations, linear-systems

1. How many solutions are there for Maxwell's equations? (Or rather, is there a finite number of them?)
2. Regardless of how many solutions to these equations exist, could we claim they form a group? If so, what properties would it have? To answer the former question, I believe said solutions would fit quite nicely into the definition of a group. Let us denote $G$ as the set of functions $E, B: \mathbb{R}^{3+1}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ that are solutions to Maxwell's equations. Then, we have:

- $G$ is a non-empty set
- $G$ has a binary operation (addition), such that:

  - $E_1+(E_2+E_3)=(E_1+E_2)+E_3$ (principle of superposition. The same applies for $B$)
  - There exists a unique identity element such that $E_I=B_I=0$
  - There exists an inverse element such that: $E_1+(-E_1)=0$ and, again, the same applies for B

The thing is Maxwell's equations involve 2 magnitudes ($E$ and $B$), so there would really be, I believe, 2 groups emerging from these equations. Nonetheless, they would not be independent, since the equations are coupled. Diving deeper into this idea, perhaps one could add rigour to the classical electromagnetic formalism. For instance, we could define variants of Poynting's vector as:

$$\vec{F}:E\times B\longrightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$$

where the classic definition $\vec{S} = \frac{1}{\mu_0}\vec{E}\wedge \vec{B}$ would just be a particular instance of $\vec{F}$.

Again, would it be of any interest to apply this group theory to classical electromagnetism? And what would the properties of the groups $E$ and $B$ be?

Comment: Every linear vector space forms a group under the binary operation of addition, however, not all groups are vector spaces. Vector spaces have a richer algebraic structure than groups in that vectors can be multiplied by scalars, can have norms, inner-products, etc. One could indeed broaden definitions like your example with the Poynting vector, however, if the broader definitions didn't have physical meaning; they would be useless in physics.

Comment: Are we talking about the solution to the vacuum equations, or to the Maxwell equations with sources?

Comment: Note that you will need to specify the question a little bit better, because the Maxwell's equations have an existence and uniqueness theorem: so you come dangerously close to saying “yeah, it's the trivial group that only contains the identity element.” it may be handy to deal with other subsets first to build an intuition, for example all of the solutions on an infinite spacetime that has no charges or currents—so, superpositions of plane waves.

Answer (score 1):

I will confine my attention to the vacuum Maxwell equations.

1. There are uncountably many solutions $\{\mathbf{E}, \mathbf{B} \}: \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3$ to the vacuum Maxwell equations.  They can be uniquely parametrized by the initial data of these solutions:  The space of functions $\{ \mathbf{E}_0(\mathbf{r}) , \mathbf{B}_0(\mathbf{r})\} = \{\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},0), \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r},0) \}$ subject to the constraints $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}_0 = \nabla \cdot \mathbf{B}_0 = 0$.
2. For the vacuum equations, the set of solutions
   $$
   \{\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t), \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r},t) | \text{vacuum Maxwell's equations hold} \}
   $$
   is a linear vector space under simultaneous addition. As you note, $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are coupled in Maxwell's equations, and so it is not possible to view this group under addition as the direct product of "$\mathbf{E}$ under addition" and "$\mathbf{B}$ under addition".  (It might be possible possible to view the set of solutions as the kernel of the "vacuum Maxwell operator" on the space of all possible vector fields $\{ \mathbf{E}, \mathbf{B} \}$ on $\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}$.  The set of all possible vector fields is a direct product of the "E-group" and "B-group" in the sense you're thinking of.  But I don't think this would be terribly enlightening.)

It's also worth noting that the set of all solutions itself has certain internal symmetries;  Maxwell's equations are invariant under the action of the [conformal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_group) as well as under [duality rotations.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/499866/symmetry-of-maxwell-equations-for-electric-magnetic-duality)  Effectively this means that the actions of these groups map solutions to other solutions.  One could possible investigate what happens to (say) the Poynting vector under these group actions. For the Poincaré group (a subgroup of the conformal group) this would just be given by the standard action of boosts & translations on the stress-energy tensor, but I'm not sure what would happen under conformal transformations or under duality rotations.